# Datatrigger listview's ItemContainer does not work when mouse is over (or selected) the specific item

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, background, datatrigger

In a ListView I bind with a DataTrigger condition the background colour of an Item (textblock) to an Integer property, because when the property changes (from 0 to 1) I want that item's background goes from transparent to red.

This trigger does not works in two cases: when the mouse is over the item, or 
when this specific item is selected.
In these two cases, the background is always transparent, despite of property's value.

So the item change its background only if the mouse is over other differents items, or other items are selected.

The textblock is defined in a separate DataTemplate (it is part of a BoardViewModel), and the ListView is the collection of these VM.
In my code I checked that there is no "isMouseOver" active trigger condition in textblock's description and that there is no "isSelected" active trigger in the listview's section.
I also tried to delete the background of the structures, but that has no effect with the problem.

--DataTemplate ---

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:BoardViewModel}">
        <Grid >

            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Grid.Row="0" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
                <Border Margin="20,20,20,20" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <TextBlock.Text>
                            <MultiBinding StringFormat="ID: {0}">
                                <Binding Path="ID"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
                </Border>
            </Grid>

        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

--- View ---

```
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <ListView Height="Auto" Background="{StaticResource BoardBackground}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path= BoardViewModels}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentBoardViewModel}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true">
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">

                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path= ErrorRedFlagByBoard}" Value="1">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path= ErrorRedFlagByBoard}" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>

                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
```

I checked the correct value of the integer property of the viewmodel, so I expected that item's background remains red also when item is selected or mouse is over the item, but something invalidate this assertion and I do not understand what. 
Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to define a custom `ControlTemplate` for the `ListViewItem`, and add your trigger to `<ControlTemplate.Triggers>`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.MouseOver.Background" Color="#1F26A0DA"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.MouseOver.Border" Color="#a826A0Da"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedInactive.Background" Color="#3DDADADA"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedInactive.Border" Color="#FFDADADA"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedActive.Background" Color="#3D26A0DA"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Item.SelectedActive.Border" Color="#FF26A0DA"/>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="False"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedInactive.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedInactive.Border}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedActive.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="{StaticResource Item.SelectedActive.Border}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path= ErrorRedFlagByBoard}" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="Red"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The triggers in the default template takes takes precedence over your triggers.

Comment: Thank you @mm8 for this solution, it works fine for me. I do not understand why to set the control template property at the beginning (as a rectangle of margin="2", SnapsTodevicePixels="true" ...) and then one other time down to code with the detailed description. Is this the only way to force Wpf understand to overwrite the custom control template listViewItem behaviour? Thank you

Comment: @GCiandro: No, the first one is the template for the FocusVisual. You don't actually need it in this case. I removed it from the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much @mm8, this is what I was looking for. In your opinion, if I have to refactor this piece of code to make it reusable for another listView in my xaml, where only the property bounded changed (ErrorRedFlagByBoard becomes  ErrorRedFlagByBoard), how could I proceed? The behaviour and the style have to be the same. Many Thanks

Comment: Sorry,  "ErrorRedFlagByBoard" becomes "ErrorRedFlagByChannel"